# Implement a Python frozenmap

Tags: python, hash-map, immutability

There are `frozenset` in Python, but no `frozendict` or `frozenmap`. I tried to implement it (Don't care too much about class naming, because I want to try to imitate the standard library) with `frozenset`, which implement O(1) time to find elements, and only calculates hash values according to all keys. The effect is almost perfect:

```
from typing import Any, NamedTuple
from collections.abc import Hashable, Mapping, Iterable, Iterator
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import starmap, repeat, chain


_value = None


class kv_pair(NamedTuple):

    key: Hashable
    value: Any

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, tuple):
            return self.key == other[0]
        elif isinstance(other, Hashable):
            global _value
            _value = self.value
            return self.key == other
        else:
            return NotImplemented

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.key)

    def __str__(self):
        return tuple.__repr__(self)

    def __repr__(self):
        return tuple.__repr__(self)


class frozenmap(Mapping):

    __slots__ = '_frozen'

    def __init__(self, iterable: Iterable = ()):
        self._frozen = frozenset(starmap(kv_pair, iterable))

    def keys(self) -> Iterable[Hashable]:
        return frozenmap_keys(self._frozen)

    def values(self) -> Iterable:
        return frozenmap_values(self._frozen)

    def items(self) -> Iterable[tuple[Hashable, Any]]:
        return frozenmap_items(self._frozen)

    def to_dict(self) -> dict:
        return dict(self._frozen)

    def get(self, key: Hashable, default=None) -> Any:
        if key in self._frozen:
            return _value
        else:
            return default

    def copy(self) -> 'frozenmap':
        return self.__class__(self._frozen)

    @classmethod
    def fromkeys(cls, keys, val=None) -> 'frozenmap':
        return cls(zip(keys, repeat(val)))

    @classmethod
    def from_dict(cls, dct: dict) -> 'frozenmap':
        return cls(dct.items())

    def __copy__(self) -> 'frozenmap':
        return self.__class__(self._frozen)

    def __bool__(self) -> bool:
        return bool(self._frozen)

    def __iter__(self) -> Iterator[tuple[Hashable, Any]]:
        return map(itemgetter(0), self._frozen)

    def __len__(self) -> int:
        return len(self._frozen)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.__class__.__name__ + '({' + ', '.join(f'{repr(k)}: {repr(v)}'for k, v in self._frozen) + '})'

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return self.__class__.__name__ + '({' + ', '.join(f'{repr(k)}: {repr(v)}'for k, v in self._frozen) + '})'

    def __eq__(self, other) -> bool:
        if isinstance(other, Mapping):
            try:
                return all(other[k] == v for k, v in self._frozen)
            except KeyError:
                return False
        else:
            return False

    def __hash__(self) -> int:
        return hash(self._frozen)

    def __contains__(self, item: Hashable) -> bool:
        return item in self._frozen

    def __getitem__(self, key: Hashable) -> Any:
        if key in self._frozen:
            return _value
        else:
            raise KeyError(key)

    def __or__(self, other) -> 'frozenmap':
        if isinstance(other, frozenmap):
            return self.__class__(chain(self._frozen, other._frozen))
        elif isinstance(other, dict):
            return self.__class__(chain(self._frozen, other.items()))
        else:
            return NotImplemented

    def __ror__(self, other) -> dict:
        if isinstance(other, dict):
            return dict(chain(self._frozen, other.items()))
        else:
            return NotImplemented


class frozenmap_keys:

    __slots__ = '_frozen'

    def __init__(self, frozen: frozenset[kv_pair]):
        self._frozen = frozen

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.__class__.__name__ + '([' + ', '.join(repr(item.key) for item in self._frozen) + '])'

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return self.__class__.__name__ + '([' + ', '.join(repr(item.key) for item in self._frozen) + '])'

    def __iter__(self) -> Iterator[Hashable]:
        return map(itemgetter(0), self._frozen)


class frozenmap_values:

    __slots__ = '_frozen'

    def __init__(self, frozen: frozenset[kv_pair]):
        self._frozen = frozen

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.__class__.__name__ + '([' + ', '.join(repr(item.value) for item in self._frozen) + '])'

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return self.__class__.__name__ + '([' + ', '.join(repr(item.value) for item in self._frozen) + '])'

    def __iter__(self) -> Iterator:
        return map(itemgetter(1), self._frozen)


class frozenmap_items:

    __slots__ = '_frozen'

    def __init__(self, frozen: frozenset[kv_pair]):
        self._frozen = frozen

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.__class__.__name__ + '([' + ', '.join(map(repr, self._frozen)) + '])'

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return self.__class__.__name__ + '([' + ', '.join(map(repr, self._frozen)) + '])'

    def __iter__(self) -> Iterator[tuple[Hashable, Any]]:
        return map(tuple, self._frozen)
```

Some test:

```
>>> a = {'123': '456', '789': 123}
>>> b = {'123': 456, 789: '123'}
>>> fa = frozenmap.from_dict(a)
>>> fb = frozenmap.from_dict(b)
>>> fa
frozenmap({'123': '456', '789': 123})
>>> fb
frozenmap({789: '123', '123': 456})
>>> fa.items()
frozenmap_items([('123', '456'), ('789', 123)])
>>> fa.keys()
frozenmap_keys(['123', '789'])
>>> fa.values()
frozenmap_values(['456', 123])
>>> a | b
{'123': 456, '789': 123, 789: '123'}
>>> fa | b
frozenmap({'789': 123, '123': '456', 789: '123'})
>>> fa | fb
frozenmap({'123': '456', 789: '123', '789': 123})
>>> a | fb
{'123': '456', 789: '123', '789': 123}
>>> a == fa
True
>>> a | fb == fa | fb
True
>>> fa['789']
123
>>> fb['123']
456
>>> ddict = {fa: a, fb: b}
>>> ddict
{frozenmap({'789': 123, '123': '456'}): {'123': '456', '789': 123}, frozenmap({789: '123', '123': 456}): {'123': 456, 789: '123'}}
>>> ddict[fa]
{'123': '456', '789': 123}
```

The implementation of the whole class relies on storing the key value pairs into the `frozenset`, and only judging the equality of the two key value pairs through the key.

But the implementation of `__getitem__` method is not good, the key to implementing is to save the value of `kv_pair` in a global variable when a key is compared with it, and then retrieve it from the global variable:

```
class kv_pair:
    ...
    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, tuple):
            return self.key == other[0]
        elif isinstance(other, Hashable):
            global _value
            _value = self.value
            return self.key == other
        else:
            return NotImplemented
    ...
```

```
class frozenmap(Mapping):
    ...
    def __getitem__(self, key: Hashable) -> Any:
        if key in self._frozen:
            return _value
        else:
            raise KeyError(key)
    ...
```

Although this should not be a problem in single threaded programs, this implementation makes me very uncomfortable. The root of the problem is that I can't get the reference of the element in the `frozenset` according to the key from `frozenset`. I haven't found a way to get it. Is it possible to get it? Or, is there a better way to implement `frozenmap`? I found people always replace it with sorted tuple from Stack Overflow, but this will lose the advantage of dictionary O(1) time looking up elements.

Comment: Without a concrete application I think this question is too abstract.

Comment: Can you please post the unit test code as well?

Comment: I'm baffled that some people think this question is too abstract. The OP is writing library code with obvious use cases. No one here would complain about the absence of a "concrete application" if someone asked for a review of a BFS function, a merge sort, or a variety of other reinvent-the-wheel questions that people use to build their programming skill -- again, because such examples are obvious library code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Library code cannot resort to global variable hacks**. You are attempting to
implement a data structure. That's a bedrock kind of library code. As such, it
cannot resort to crazy mechanisms like setting a global variable as a sneaky
workaround for a situation where you need to recover a key-value linkage that
was severed during class instantiation.

**When you find yourself tempted to do something crazy, stop and do some
research**. Python doesn't have a frozenmap, but it's not a new idea. [PEP
416](https://peps.python.org/pep-0416/) explored the idea as a formal proposal.
ActiveState has a [code recipe](https://code.activestate.com/recipes/414283/)
for a frozendict. There are [third-party frozendict](https://github.com/Marco-Sulla/python-frozendict)
implementations. Those links
are fairly easy to read, understand, and learn from. In particular, the PEP
contains links to a variety of other implementations worth looking at. While I
explored the topic briefly, I also came across an [idea for an immutable
dict](https://adamj.eu/tech/2022/01/05/how-to-make-immutable-dict-in-python/)
based on Python's new-ish MappingProxyType.

**Unhelpful type proliferation: kv_pair, frozenmap_keys, frozenmap_values,
frozenmap_items**. None of these types seem to help very much. Remember: a
frozenmap is immutable. Given that, a tuple would be a perfectly acceptable way
to represent its keys. Ditto for its values. And its items could just be a
tuple of tuples. As for `kv_pair`, it's not doing anything useful other than
supporting the global variable hack via its unusual implementation of
`__eq__()`.

**You don't need to destroy the underlying key-value mappings**. You can
receive the inputs, build a dict, tuck that dict away as a quasi-private
attribute, and then implement the rest of the needed behavior: hashing,
iteration, lookup, raising on attempts to mutate, and so forth. Some of the
implementations noted above achieve such things by inheriting from dict,
disabling methods that mutate, and implementing a hashing approach. Others do
it by building a class from the ground up with the desired dict API. Either
way, you can still use a Python dict behind the scenes for underlying data
storage. Alternatively, if you really want to go hardcore, implement your own
hashmap for storage. Either way, you'll be using something dict-like (rather
than destroying the relationships and then hacking your way back to
recover lost linkages).